# Formal definition of "planar graph"

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, definition, plane-geometry

The [wikipedia definition of "planar graph"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) says:

> In graph theory, a planar graph is a graph that can be embedded in the plane, i.e., it can be drawn on the plane in such a way that its edges intersect only at their endpoints.

I think this is a quite good description, and one quickly understands what is meant by "planar graph". But to me, the definition seems to be informal. How can one formally define the concepts "drawing on the plane" and "the edges don't cross"?

Comment: This definition is not informal, it's the actual definition.

Comment: @Crostul: I agree that it's the actual definition. But I still think that it's informal.

Comment: @user7280899 It's not entirely formal: it doesn't say what "embedded" means, except through the informal explanation about drawing it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a number of ways. For example, we could have an injective function $f : V(G) \to \mathbb R^2$ giving the coordinates of the vertices. For every edge $vw \in E(G)$, we could have a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)) from $f(v)$ to $f(w)$: a continuous function $h_{vw} : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ with $h_{vw}(0) = f(v)$ and $h_{vw}(1) = f(w)$. To ensure that the edges don't cross, we could require that for two edges $e_1, e_2$ the corresponding functions $h_1$, $h_2$ don't have $h_1(s) = h_2(t)$ unless both $s$ and $t$ are either $0$ or $1$.

Because the specific topological definition doesn't affect the combinatorial meaning too much, we can play around with this definition to get something easier to work with. For example, rather than making $h_{vw}$ continuous, we could ask for it to be smooth, or piecewise linear. The goal would be to make it easier to prove obvious-sounding geometrical properties of the embedding. For example, you might not want to invoke the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) just to say that every cycle in the graph has an inside and an outside.

Ultimately, we leave these details out of the definition because the details don't matter much - various ways to fill in the details produce the same notion of planar graphs.

In fact, since every planar graph has a straight-line embedding, we could even make the edges be line segments $[f(v), f(w)]$ and require their interiors to be disjoint. But this is probably less convenient to work with.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I agree that it's good to leave the details out of the definition. But it's definitely good to once think about how it could be formalized.

Comment: Also, $f$ has to be injective.

Comment: How hard is it to prove that every planar graph has a straight-line embedding?

Comment: @Paul Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Wikipedia's article on [Fáry's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem) has a proof; it isn't long.

Comment: Thank you (I guess I shoulda tried googling it)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Of course, the proof has some innocent-lloking details such as " If $n ≥ 3$, then all faces of $G$ must be triangles, as we could add an edge into any face with more sides while preserving planarity, contradicting the assumption of maximal planarity" -- The ability to add an edge appears obvious and at the same time about as tough as the Jordan curve theorem, I guess