# How can we formalise the notion of the face of a planar graph?

Tags: graph-theory, definition, planar-graphs

I am looking for a way to formalise the notion of the face of a planar graph. I have read through the following links on stack exchange: [formal definition of a planar graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3073581/formal-definition-of-planar-graph),  [definition of a separating triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960367/definition-of-a-separating-triangle-in-planar-graph/3970038#3970038), [face of a non-planar graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206414/faces-of-a-non-planar-graph), [notion of a face in graph theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143381/notion-of-face-in-the-graph-theory). I also have an introductory graph textbook that only makes passing mention that faces can be defined via a 'generalization of the Jordan curve theorem'. I am trying to formalise these notions in order to formalise (to some extent) another proof that uses graph theory in a very intuitive way. My main issue is I cannot seem to fill in the gaps using the Jordan curve theorem to define a face in a way that deals with every case.

I define a planar graph in the following way: Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph. We say $G$ is planar if the following hold: (i) there exists an injective function $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, (ii) for every edge $v_iv_j \in E$, there exists a Jordan arc from $f(v_i)$ to $f(v_j)$, and, no two Jordan arcs intersect except possibly at the image of a vertex under $f$.

Attempt at defining a face: Suppose we have a planar embedding of a planar graph $G$. Suppose there is a closed path of $G$ passing through the vertices $(v,v_1,v_2,...,v_k,v)$. By definition of a planar graph, there are Jordan arcs between $f(v)$ and $f(v_1)$, $f(v_1)$ and $f(v_2)$, etc. The union of all of these Jordan arcs give us a Jordan curve. By the Jordan curve theorem, there is an interior region. **If** there is no vertex, $v_i$, such that $f(v_i)$ lies in the interior, we call the interior region an **interior face** of the planar embedding. The exterior face is defined as the plane minus the planar embedding of $G$ and minus all interior faces.

The above definition is verbose, but works in simple cases, like the graph below with two faces.

[image: A simple graph with two faces]

However, this definition fails for the following two planar embeddings (of the same graph):

[image]

[image]

Here I do not know how to alter my definition to account for these situations when there is a topological 'line' in what would otherwise be a face.

Can anyone point me to a resource or provide a rigorous definition? In particular I am looking for explicit details, rather than simply knowing that it can be done via the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: Maybe have a look at "Primitives for the Manipulation of General Subdivisions and the Computation of Voronoi Diagrams, Guibas & Stolfi, January 1983, ACM Transactions on Graphics 4(2):221-234".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for this, it was very helpful! The only thing I could not parse from their exposition is from the definition of a boundary as a closed path; for example, what happens in the cases of a planar embedding where the image of a vertex lies within the face (for example in my last picture)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be rigorous, you should not talk about a face of a planar graph, but a face of a planar embedding of a graph, or a face of a plane graph. This is because, as in your example, different embeddings may have different faces.

Here is the definition that I use and that I find in several books that I own: given an embedding $(\phi_e : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2)_{e \in E}$ of a planar graph $(V,E)$, a face is a connected region of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \bigcup_{e \in E} \phi_e([0,1])$.

This is rigorous, but it does not give you much unfortunately. It is not even obvious that the number of faces is finite for instance. The next steps would probably be to prove that if $G$ is connected then each face has a boundary that is a closed walk in $G$, and each edge appears in at most 2 such boundaries, but it also depends on what you want to prove.

Comment: Thank you, this sort of simple definition is what I was looking for! However can I clarify one thing; here we assume there exist connected regions, and in fact it is intuitively obvious the plane minus the embedding is the union of connected regions. But to rigorously justify this, must we invoke the Jordan curve theorem?

Comment: Any subset of the plane is a union of connected regions. We'll have to invoke the Jordan curve theorem to say more specific things about what they are in this case. (Some textbooks sidestep the Jordan curve theorem by requiring all edges in an embedding to be piecewise linear curves, in which case everything is a polygon.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I realise that now... I also realise I could treat the edge embeddings as linear (or piecewise linear), but actually the result I am trying to prove has as a corollary that every planar graph has a 'straight line' embedding

Comment: I don't think it's silly to start by considering only piecewise linear embeddings, and prove that they can actually be straight lines. Piecewise linear edges can have any number of pieces they want, so they actually allow you to approximately draw any picture you like - that's very flexible.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have thought about it a little more, and I am not quite sure what is meant by 'connected region'. I understand $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \cup \phi_e$ is simply a subset of the plane; and intuitively the faces form the 'connected regions'. However, we can arbitrarily split any 'face' into smaller 'connected regions'. These 'smaller' connected regions should not be faces; and yet I cannot see the distinction between them and the actual faces in terms of them being "connected regions" as defined?

Comment: @MishaLavrov That's a good point. I'm going to spend a bit of time thinking about that. I think I have been very focused on the JCT because virtually every resource I have read makes some passing reference to it when it comes to formalising the notion of a face

Comment: @MishaLavrov My apologies to you and Guyslain for the multiple comments; I just wanted to clarify I now understand exactly what is going on (so you don't need to spend time replying). I found in a textbook that a "region" is defined as arcwise connected components, and so now it all makes sense!

Comment: Arcwise connected components indeed, so the regions are maximal in term of being connected. You're welcome to comment more if you need more help.